# Setting up a wireless network at home

Tags: wireless-networking

Looking to connect up the new apartment.  Renting so can't
install cables around the place so going to try make sure
I configure the Wireless so both strength and speed are good
both for internal file transfer and connecting to internet.

Internet connection 10/20mb line (may upgrade from 10)

Equipment:

● Dell PC with Windows Vista running on it. (2 rooms away from
the point of the wireless router.)

● Mac Book Pro

● XBox 360 (right beside in point)

● Dell Laptop

- I'm looking to share files between all devices if possible.

Few basics I'm working on

1. The 'G' Wireless speeds are plenty fast for connecting to
   internet as my internet connection is only 10mbs and 'G'
   goes up to 54?
2. if I want to use the 'N' Standard I'll need to update
   my standard Cisco EPC2425 router or turn off the wireless
   on it and connect a more powerful router by cable?
3. Can I get up to 104mbs on the Cisco router?
   ( http://short.ie/sngnyu - pdf doc on this device)
   to follow from that would this ( http://short.ie/wwd4u9

   - D-Link AirPlus XtremeG - 108Mbps Super G Wireless 802.11g
     PCI Adapter) be able to connect to the Cisco router
     at up to 104mbs?  In the pdf for the cisco router it
     just says:

" ● 802.11g Wireless Access Point with 4 service set identifiers
   (SSIDs)

● Wireless Protected Setup (WPS), including a push button
   switch to activate WPS for
   simplified and secure wireless setup "

UPDATE:

A person has suggested the best way get my PC connected at fast speeds is using "homeplugs"

Sounds like it just might be the best way? any thoughts or gotchas to watch out for?

Comment: I think you're referring to networking over home wiring. This form of networking may not be wise for an apartment building. It sounds like your current wireless setup will be more reliable and just as fast (if not faster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 'G' Wireless speeds are plenty fast for connecting to internet as my internet connection is only 10mbs and 'G' goes up to 54?

You're right. The 802.11g standard is fine for that.

> if I want to use the 'N' Standard I'll need to update my standard Cisco EPC2425 router or turn off the wireless on it and connect a more powerful router by cable?

I don't believe that model supports the 802.11n standard. The 802.11n standard only sees speed gains over 802.11g when it operates on the 5Ghz frequencies. However, for this speed increase you get diminished range. 
Since you have a good 802.11g router, you may want to maintain two routers, one for 802.11g on 2.4Ghz and one for 802.11n on 5Ghz.  You could use inexpensive n router to act as a simple wireless bridge. 

Most new routers can operate on both frequency ranges at the same time. So if two routers sounds too complicated, feel free to simply replace the one you have.

> Can I get up to 104mbs on the Cisco router? ( http://short.ie/sngnyu - pdf doc on this device) to follow from that would this ( http://short.ie/wwd4u9 )D-Link AirPlus XtremeG - 108Mbps Super G Wireless 802.11g PCI Adapter) be able to connect to the Cisco router at up to 104mbs?

I believe those D-Link routers use two 802.11g transmitters linked together. They advertise 108 Mbps (54 * 2 = 108), but the actual speeds are much lower. In order for this to work, you often need a D-link receiver with the same proprietary technology. This is not part of the 802.11g standard. You're much better off with a router that supports the 802.11n standard.

Answer (score 2):

Something to consider, as well, is the size of your apartment and the materials it's made out of.

My apartment is about 700 ft² (65m²) and my Linksys WRT-54G covers it just fine. The problems I have revolve the adapters. Some are good, some are cheap. Unless you have the money to spare, upgrading your router probably isn't necessary. But @jweede is right. If you are going to get a .11n router, attach it as a bridge. (Set the wireless settings, then disable the DHCP server, if enabled.)

I would, though, get a .11n PCI(-Express) card for your desktop computer. They're generally able to connect to .11g routers, and from my experience, tend to function better than .11g adapters.

Inevitably, file sharing is generally simple. Windows doesn't block it by default, and the XBox will generally see the Windows PCs. As for your Mac, I've never successfully done file sharing between the two OSes, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Macs are super-easy to talk to windows machines. Turn on 'Windows Sharing' in your Mac Preferences, and *poof* visible to Windows, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try that. I know I've gotten my friend's MacBook to see my stuff, but not vice-versa. Hope this works!